# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3) while testing zip function

Tags: python

I am trying to test the zip function with a simple script. Here is my code:

```
list1os = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
List1is = [11,12,13]
List1name = ['Stacey']
list2os = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
List2is = [14,15,16]
List2name = ['Donna']
list3 = [3,4,5,6,7,8]

test1=[]
test2=[]
inst_chunk_of_values_id=[]

#Creating data to test
test1.append(List1is)
test1.append(list1os)
test1.append(List1name)

test2.append(List2is)
test2.append(list2os)
test2.append(List2name)

inst_chunk_of_values_id.append(test1)
inst_chunk_of_values_id.append(test2)

#trying to split up the dataset here
for chunk1,chunk2 in zip(inst_chunk_of_values_id[0],inst_chunk_of_values_id[1]):

    print(chunk1)
    os_range1,is_range1,chk_roll_id1 = chunk1
    os_range2,is_range2,_=chunk2
```

I am trying to pass `inst_chunk_of_values_id` through the zip function.

`inst_chunk_of_values_id` looks like:

```
[[[11, 12, 13], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], ['Stacey']], [[14, 15, 16], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], ['Donna']]]
```

I am trying to assign to the data so my desired output looks like:

```
os_range1 = [11, 12, 13]
is_range1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
chk_roll_id1 = ['Stacey']

os_range2 = [14, 15, 16]
is_range2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
chk_roll_id2 = ['Donna']
```

but I get the following error:

```
    os_range1,is_range1,chk_roll_id1 = chunk1    
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Why am I getting this?

Comment: You are trying to read [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] into 3 variables, but there are 10 variables.

Comment: If you want to pair adjacent lists in zip you can use: `zip(inst_chunk_of_values_id[::2],inst_chunk_of_values_id[1::2])`. If you just have 2 items, the directly assigning it going to be better.

Comment: Maybe the last loop should be just `for chunk in inst_chunk_of_values_id:` and then print given `chunk` as you want.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's worth noting that someone did not like this question. We can only guess why; my feeling is that the question contained your usual begging and pleading, and some people find that irritating. Statements of woe and suffering may strike the reader as coercive or manipulative, which one reason why technical writing is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

### I think using a `dict` might be a easier

- Presumably you have more than `Stacey` and `Donna`, so the following code will allow you to unpack any number of cases.
- `dictionaries` are more useful for creating many variables.

### Synthetic Data

- Expanded data

```py
import numpy as np

names = ['Stacey', 'Donna', 'Sam', 'Don']
np.random.seed(365)
test = {name: [list(np.random.randint(10, size=3)), list(np.random.randint(10, size=10)), [name]] for name in names}

test_zip = list(zip(*test.values()))

print(test_zip)

[([2, 4, 1], [7, 7, 0], [1, 6, 5], [0, 1, 4]),
 ([5, 2, 2, 9, 8, 4, 0, 3, 3, 7],
  [8, 4, 3, 2, 6, 2, 6, 8, 9, 6],
  [7, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 8, 7, 9, 9],
  [0, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 5, 3, 2, 7]),
 (['Stacey'], ['Donna'], ['Sam'], ['Don'])]
```

### Unpack the data

```py
data = dict()
for i, c in enumerate(test_zip, start=1):
    if i == 1:
        for i, x in enumerate(c, start=1):
            data[f'os_range{i}'] = x
    if i == 2:
        for i, x in enumerate(c, start=1):
            data[f'is_range{i}'] = x
    if i == 3:
        for i, x in enumerate(c, start=1):
            data[f'chk_roll_id{i}'] = x
```

#### Output

```py
print(data)

{'os_range1': [2, 4, 1],
 'os_range2': [7, 7, 0],
 'os_range3': [1, 6, 5],
 'os_range4': [0, 1, 4],
 'is_range1': [5, 2, 2, 9, 8, 4, 0, 3, 3, 7],
 'is_range2': [8, 4, 3, 2, 6, 2, 6, 8, 9, 6],
 'is_range3': [7, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 8, 7, 9, 9],
 'is_range4': [0, 9, 6, 5, 6, 9, 5, 3, 2, 7],
 'chk_roll_id1': ['Stacey'],
 'chk_roll_id2': ['Donna'],
 'chk_roll_id3': ['Sam'],
 'chk_roll_id4': ['Don']}
```